# Reference: unique differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

There have been at least [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24930/differentiable-structures-on-r3) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16035/a-reference-for-smooth-structures-on-rn) on MathOverflow asking about the uniqueness of differentiable structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \neq 4$). However, on neither page is an explicit reference or proof of the case I'm interested in: $n=1$.

In the comments of one of them, the following solution is given: "one can put a Riemannian metric on any smooth $\mathbb{R}^1$ and then the exponential map from a given point defines a diffeomorphism from the standard $\mathbb{R}^1$ to the smooth $\mathbb{R}^1$". Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with either Riemannian metrics or the exponential map.

Does anyone have a proof, or a reference to a proof, of this result that is more elementary? Or is that as simple as it gets?

Comment: Milnor's Topology from the Differential Viewpoint http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Milnor%20Topology%20from%20%23681EA.pdf contains a proof (in the appendix, at the end).  It uses the notion of arc length of a curve, so kind of implicitly uses Riemannian metrics...

Comment: +1 for Milnor's proof, because it's nice and 3 small pages long.

Comment: @Randall Agreed! It seems to be exactly what I was looking for: not having to dive into the abstract machinery of Riemannian metrics. I hoped there was a way to prove it, in the same spirit, that was longer but more elementary.

Comment: @Sambo: There is also a proof based on the existence of an integral curve for a vector field. If $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$ is your possibly exotic $\mathbb{R}$, you can define what it means for a tangent vector to positive, show that the collection of tangent vectors is a non-empty cone (i.e, half-space), show using partition of unity that you have a positive vector field and then show that an integral curve of this vector field gives you a diffeomorphism between $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$ and an open interval. I think there is an exercise along these lines in Lee's book.